# Form does not rotate around center axis (x,y)

Tags: css

Even though I have set [transform-origin: 100% 50%;] in css, the form does not rotate around its center in comparison to X- and Y- axis.

**Question:** How can I make the form rotate counted exactly from its midpoint.

```css
    .box {
      background-color: pink;
      margin: 300px 0 0 300px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }
    
    .box {
      position: absolute;
      animation: spin 10s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    .line-horizontal {
      background-color: black;
      width: 200px;
      height: 5px;
      margin: 100px 0 0 0;
    }
    
    .line-vertical {
      background-color: black;
      width: 5px;
      height: 200px;
      margin: -105px 0 0 100px;
    }
    
    @keyframes spin {
      from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform-origin: 100% 50%;
      }
      to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
```

```html
    
    <div class="box">
      <div class="line-horizontal"></div>
      <div class="line-vertical"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: the center is 50% 50% ... and you should specify this in the element not the keyframe or it will get animated also

Comment: `transform-origin: center;`, which is the same as `50% 50%` ... and it is very well showed/explained in the docs, e,g, MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: @Temani Afif Your suggestion works. Pls move it into an answer and I will approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `tranform-origin` to `50% 50%` instead which means the center in both axis and don't put it inside the keyframes because it will get animated

```css
.box {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  animation: spin 10s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  /*center*/
}

.line-horizontal {
  background-color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
}

.line-vertical {
  background-color: black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: -105px 0 0 100px;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="line-horizontal"></div>
  <div class="line-vertical"></div>
</div>
```

You can also simplify your code like below in case you need the same visual:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) center/100% 5px,
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) center/5px 100%,
    pink;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  animation: spin 10s forwards;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%; /* OR center*/
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```